# Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS slow on Lenovo Legion Y520

Tags: 20.04, lenovo, laptop, performance, minecraft

I have changed the OS on my Lenovo Legion Y520 to Ubuntu a few months ago. Before that I was running an unlicensed Windows 10 Version. I found out after a longer time of using it so I switched to a Linux distro. I was expecting some performance improvements with Ubuntu as it was getting slower and some features did not work on it at all (on the old OS). Most things got fixed, however there is still a problem I am unable to find the cause of. When running a game or something similarly high performance, it becomes impossible to run any other app without experiencing huge lags while trying to navigate through apps, settings, anything for that matter. For example, running Minecraft and listening to Spotify at the same time is impossible.

I read through the forums and from what I could find, I have to make some adjustments so that Ubuntu works together with the hardware properly. I have no idea how to do that as I am pretty new to this, but I added a screenshot from while Minecraft was running.

Results of `top` :

[image: top_performance-measure]

Comment: Lenovo Legion Y520 comes with Nvidia graphics. Did you select the option to install drivers when installing Ubuntu? Or at least installed them after? And di you disabled Secure Boot in UEFI? Lastly and less important, why did you install a 2 years old release, why not 22.04?

Comment: btw I would say that it's a strange swap size (maybe nothing to do with your problem)

Comment: @ChanganAuto I will have to install those drivers... thank you. I cannot access the BIOS (It doesn't have UEFI as I was unable to upgrade it because... I got this laptop from someone who got it from someone else, and so we don't know the BIOS password etc., big bummer). I installed this update in 2021, 22.4 was not out yet.

Comment: @Andra I am not sure what those numbers are, megabytes? I saw that the minimum recommended swap space for an 8GB RAM System should be 3-11MGs, source: [Adding and Managing Ubuntu 20.04 Swap Space](https://www.answertopia.com/ubuntu/adding-and-managing-ubuntu-swap-space/), this would mean it is in a bad state now (too little swap space). I am really not sure about it as I am not sure in what format those numbers are printed here.

Comment: it seems that for 8GB RAM you have a 1GB swap. Is it now possible to enlarge it?

Comment: If you can't disable Secure Boot then you'll have to use `mokutil` to sign the Nvidia drivers. Nvidia drivers are required for optimal performance. Complaining about performance or comparing it to Windows without the graphics drivers is nonsensical. Not as much as buying a 2nd hand computer with password protected UEFI (you don't have BIOS; BIOS isn't used since 2012) and not knowing it, of course.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thank you. This laptop is that old, that it still uses BIOS and it was passed on to me, I did not buy it, that is ridiculous. I have friends that tried to fix the BIOS pw problem with me and even they were amazed how this laptop only has BIOS still after all this time. So yes, it is old af,